# Problems with obtaining last cell in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a code to create a pivot table (as part of a much larger code) and I just can't get it to detect the source data. Unfortunately, each time the code will run the data will be of a different number of rows, so I want the code to automatically find the last cell with data in it.
I keep getting errors stating that an object is required or a variable is not defined. Despite going to the VBA error guide, I cant find what is wrong.

Can anyone see what the problem here is? Or even if there is a more efficient way to do it?

```
Sub CreatePivotTable()
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As Range, LRow As Range, LCol As Range

'Determine the data range you want to pivot
 Set LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
 Set LCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
 Set SrcData = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:Cells(LRow,LCol)")

'Create a new worksheet
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Pivot Table"
'Where do you want Pivot Table to start?
    StartPvt = Worksheets("Occupancy").Range("A15")

'Create Pivot Cache from Source Data
Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase,  SourceData:=SrcData)

'Create Pivot table from Pivot Cache
    Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=StartPvt, TableName:="Occupancy")

'Create the headings and row and column orientation
    pvt.PivotFields("Precinct").Orientation = xlPageField
    pvt.PivotFields("Number").Orientation.xlDataField.Function = xlCount
    pvt.PivotFields("Captured Date").Orientation.xlColumnField.Position = 1
    pvt.PivotFields("Captured Session").Orientation.xlColumnField.Position = 2
    pvt.PivotFields("Session Location").Orientation.xlRowField.Position = 1

'Turn on Automatic updates/calculations --like screenupdating to speed up code
    pvt.ManualUpdate = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `Set SrcData = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1").CurrentRegion`  Assuming you have no blank rows or columns in your dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Anything within quotes is a string and hence `"A1:Cells(LRow,LCol)"` becomes a string and doesn't take the address of the cells(LRow,LCol)

Change

```
Set SrcData = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:Cells(LRow,LCol)")
```

to

```
LastCol = Split(Cells(, LCol).Address, "$")(1)
Set SrcData = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:" & LastCol & LRow)
```

or to this

```
Set SrcData = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:" & Cells(LRow,LCol).Address(False, False))
```

Also change

```
Dim LRow As Range, LCol As Range

Set LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Set LCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

to

```
Dim LRow As Long, LCol As Long

LRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
LCol = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
```

Comment: LCol and LRow are being declared as Ranges. That's another issue here and it's specifically what's causing his "object is required" error (`Set Range = Long`). You should also change the Dim to the expected types.

Comment: @Mikegrann: Good Point. I missed that

Comment: Thanks all. I think the error has gone. Unfortunately I cannot tell as it now says "Reference is not valid" referring to the line     Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=StartPvt, TableName:="Occupancy")

Comment: @user6661501: See [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659224/pivotcaches-add-errors-out) link on how to create from pivotcache.You have to give the address in RC format

Answer (score 0):

Use a table to store the data and give it a name. Then set the pivot source to the table name