# VBA Error (Type MIsmatch) when create a pivot table

Tags: vba, excel

Hi I'm working on my VBA code to set a range based on the last row in my source data and then create a pivot table on that range.  The messagebox gives me the right last row number in source data. However the last line here goes wrong when I run the code with error (Error type mismatch).Could you please help me to fix? thanks.

```
Dim PvtTbl As pivotTable
Dim wsData As Worksheet
Dim rngData As Range
Dim PvtTblCache As PivotCache
Dim wsPvtTbl As Worksheet
Dim pvtFld As PivotField


Set wsData = Worksheets("Task List Data Export")

Set wsPvtTbl = Worksheets("Summary")

wsPvtTbl.Cells.Clear
wsPvtTbl.Cells.ColumnWidth = 10

For Each PvtTbl In wsPvtTbl.PivotTables
If MsgBox("Delete existing PivotTable!", vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
PvtTbl.TableRange2.Clear
End If
Next PvtTbl

Dim last As Long

With Worksheets("Task List Data Export")
    last = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

End With
MsgBox last

Set rngData = Nothing

With wsData
Set rngData = wsData.Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(last, 15))
End With

ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=rngData, Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=wsPvtTbl.Range("B25"), TableName:="PivotTable1", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

This code worked perfectly with my original data source. However I generated the source file today (updated) and then the code is no longer working. I don't think there is a big problem with the source data because I can still create pivot table manually with defined range.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Try [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659224/pivotcaches-add-errors-out) Specally how you change it to R1C1 `MyPivotRangeName = "'" & ws.Name & "'!" & MyPivotRange.Address(ReferenceStyle = xlR1C1)` and then use that

Comment: Code runs fine here, the above as well as the reference style that Siddarth suggests. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa264979(v=vs.60).aspx for Type Mismatch error generic info.