# Error 13 While creating a PivotTable

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I keep having the same error "13" "type incompatibility" while doing a pivot table.

```
Sub tracer()

Dim cache As PivotCache
Dim table As PivotTable
Dim prange As range
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim lastcol As Long

lastrow = data.Cells(data.Rows.count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
lastcol = 15

Set prange = data.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastrow, lastcol)
graphe_clos.Select

Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=prange)
Set table = cache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=graphe_clos.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="Terminator")        

End Sub
```

Thank you for Help

Comment: Your code works for me. ok try this. Replace `Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=prange)` with this line and check if you still get the error? `Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=data.Cells(1, 1).Resize(lastrow, lastcol))`

Comment: same error @SiddharthRout

Comment: Which excel version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Excel 2013

Comment: What is the exact error message that you are getting? 13 is for type mismatch

Comment: Also for testing purpose can you try this as well? `Set cache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(xlDatabase, "'" & Data.Name & "'!" & prange.Address)`

Comment: it's working. can you explain the **`"'" & Data.Name & "'!"`**

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/Excel.PivotCaches.Create Inspite of that excel sometime creates a problem so I am passing it as a string For example `'Data'!A1:A10`

Comment: I remember suggesting someone the same thing so I was saerching for it. And [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659224/pivotcaches-add-errors-out) is what I got. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/178540/discussion-between-ibrahim-atto-and-siddharth-rout).

Comment: How can i bypass the pivotfields method? it's not working `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Terminator").PivotFields("Evt F")
          .Orientation = xlColumnField
          .Position = 1
    End With`

Comment: @Ibrahimatto see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The safer way to assign `SourceData` to your `PivotCache` is by using the following line

```
Set Cache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pRange.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))
```

adding the fourth parameter `xlExternal` verifies that the range is also pulling the worksheet's name.

See more explanation inside the code's comments.

Modified Code

```
Sub tracer()

Dim Cache As PivotCache
Dim Table As PivotTable
Dim pRange As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim LastCol As Long

' use With statement to shorten and fully qualify all your nested objects
With Data
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    LastCol = 15

    ' set the Range of the Pivot's data
    Set pRange = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(LastRow, LastCol))

    ' graphe_clos.Select '<-- you don't need to "Select" the sheet in order to create the Pivot-Table
End With

' set the Pivot Cache
Set Cache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=pRange.Address(False, False, xlA1, xlExternal))

' set the Pivot Table
Set Table = Cache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=graphe_clos.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="Terminator")

End Sub
```

Regarding your latest question, modify:

```
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Terminator").PivotFields("Evt F")
```

With

```
With Table.PivotFields("Evt F")
```

since you already set your `PivotTable` object to `Table`.

Comment: It's working. Do you think `Table.AddDataField graphe_clos.PivotTables _
    ("Terminator").PivotFields("Descriptifs"), "Nombre de Descriptifs", xlCount`is the best way to add a data field or you have something much efficient