# Method add of object "PivotCaches" failed runtime error 404

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I recorded a macro that creates a pivot table but A 440 runtime error is always appearing. My excel book only contains 3 sheets that are sheet1 sheet2 and sheet3 . Please I need to know why this error is appearing it was working fine. I tried to search online for the error but nothing solved my problems.

This line is causing the error

> Set PTCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase,
>   SourceData:=PRange)

If anyone has any suggestions please help

here is my code

```
Option Explicit

' This function is used to calculate the number of rows
Function lastrow() As Long
Dim ix As Long
ix = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
lastrow = ix
End Function

Sub Create_Pivot_table()

' Declaring variables
Dim WSD As Worksheet
Dim WSD1 As Worksheet
Dim PTCache As PivotCache
Dim PT As PivotTable
Dim PF As PivotField
Dim PRange As Range
Dim FinalRow As Long
Dim FinalCol As Long
Set WSD = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
Set WSD1 = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(2)

Dim n As Integer
Dim last As Long
Dim ph_flag, sp_flag, up_flag As Boolean
ph_flag = False
sp_flag = False
up_flag = False
last = lastrow() - 1

' Delete any prior pivot tables
For Each PT In WSD1.PivotTables
    PT.TableRange2.Clear
Next PT

' Define input area and set up a Pivot Cache
FinalRow = WSD.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).row
FinalCol = WSD.Cells(1, Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column
Set PRange = WSD.Cells(1, 1).Resize(FinalRow, FinalCol)
Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)
' Create the Pivot Table from the Pivot Cache
Set PT = PTCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=WSD1.Cells(1, 1), TableName:="PivotTable1")

' Turn off updating while building the table
PT.ManualUpdate = False

With PT.PivotFields("DEPT_CODE")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With

With PT.PivotFields("MAJR_CODE1")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 2
End With

With PT.PivotFields("Adviser")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 3
End With



With PT.PivotFields("CLAS_CODE")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .Subtotals = Array(False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False, False)
    .PivotItems("FR").Position = 1
    .PivotItems("SO").Position = 2
    .PivotItems("JR").Position = 3
    .PivotItems("SR").Position = 4
    .PivotItems("PG").Position = 5
    .PivotItems("GR").Position = 6
    .Position = 1
End With

With PT.PivotFields("STYP_DESC")
    .Orientation = xlColumnField
    .PivotItems("new").Position = 1
    .Position = 2
End With

' Set up the data fields
With PT.PivotFields("ID")
    .Orientation = xlDataField
    .Function = xlCount
    .Position = 1
End With

' Calc the pivot table
PT.ManualUpdate = False
PT.ManualUpdate = True

'***************************************************************************
'Format Pivot Table
PT.ShowDrillIndicators = False
PT.RowAxisLayout xlTabularRow

Sheets("Sheet2").Select

' Shading the first 2 rows in the sheet
    ActiveSheet.Rows("2:3").Select
    ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Activate
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.799981688894314
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

' Shading the grand total (row)
PT.PivotSelect "'Row Grand Total'", _
        xlDataAndLabel, True
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

' Shading the grand total (column)
PT.PivotSelect "'Column Grand Total'", _
        xlDataAndLabel, True
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

' DEPT_CODE COLUMN
' Putting a thick border the Dept_Code total
' Thick border on the Department
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
PT.PivotSelect "DEPT_CODE[All]", _
        xlLabelOnly, True
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

' MAJOR_CODE COLUMN
' Thick border on the Major
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    PT.PivotSelect "MAJR_CODE1[All]", _
        xlLabelOnly, True
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

' ADVISER COLUMN
' Apply to ALL cells thin border
    Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
    PT.PivotSelect "Adviser[All]", xlLabelOnly _
        , True
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
' Thick border for Adviser
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

' CLASS_CODE COLUMNS
' Shading the new columns
PT.PivotSelect "new", xlDataAndLabel, True
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With




' MAJOR_CODE_TOTAL ROW
' Shading MAJOR_CODE_TOTAL
Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical).LineStyle = xlNone
Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal).LineStyle = xlNone
PT.PivotSelect "MAJR_CODE1[All;Total]", _
        xlDataAndLabel, True
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight2
        .TintAndShade = 0.599993896298105
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With



' DEPT_TOTAL row
' Shading the DEPT_TOTAL row
PT.PivotSelect "DEPT_CODE[All;Total]", _
        xlDataAndLabel, True
    With Selection.Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent1
        .TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

' CLASS_CODE COLUMNS
' Thin All borders
  Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
  Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
  With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

    For n = 1 To 30
        If Cells(2, n) = "SP" Then
        sp_flag = True
        Exit For
        End If
    Next

    If sp_flag Then
        PT.PivotSelect "FR:SP", xlDataAndLabel, _
        True
    End If




    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

PT.PivotSelect "new", xlDataAndLabel, True
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

' MAJOR_CODE TOTAL ROW
' Apply a thick border
    PT.PivotSelect "MAJR_CODE1[All;Total]", _
        xlDataAndLabel, True
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

' DEPT_TOTAL ROW
' Apply a thick border
    PT.PivotSelect "DEPT_CODE[All;Total]", _
        xlDataAndLabel, True
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlMedium
    End With

    ' This is for the Grand Total
    Dim last1 As Long
    last1 = lastrow() - 1
    'Columns("R:R").Select
    Range("R1:R" & last1).Select
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalDown).LineStyle = xlNone
    Selection.Borders(xlDiagonalUp).LineStyle = xlNone
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeLeft)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeBottom)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeRight)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideVertical)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With
    With Selection.Borders(xlInsideHorizontal)
        .LineStyle = xlContinuous
        .ColorIndex = 0
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .Weight = xlThin
    End With

'***************************************************************************
'copy pivot to new sheet

    'Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    'Selection.Clear
    'Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Sheets("Sheet3").UsedRange.Clear
    ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable1").PivotSelect "", xlDataAndLabel, True
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Sheet3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteFormats, Operation:=xlNone, _
        SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
    ActiveSheet.Rows(1).Delete

    Range("A1:A2").Select
    Selection.Merge
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Department"
    Range("A1:A2").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True

    Range("B1:B2").Select
    Selection.Merge
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Major"
    Range("B1:B2").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True


    Range("C1:C2").Select
    Selection.Merge
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "Adviser"
    Range("C1:C2").Select
    With Selection
        .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
        .VerticalAlignment = xlCenter
        .WrapText = False
        .Orientation = 0
        .AddIndent = False
        .IndentLevel = 0
        .ShrinkToFit = False
        .ReadingOrder = xlContext
        .MergeCells = True
    End With
    Selection.Font.Bold = True


    ActiveSheet.Cells.Select
    ActiveSheet.Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit

End Sub

Sub Rearrange_Col()
Dim n As Integer
Dim m As Integer

n = 0
m = 9

ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Select

Do While n < m
    If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "new" Then
        ' Check the next cell to be cur
        If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 1).Value = "cur" Then
            ' Check the next cell
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        End If

    Else
        'MsgBox "need to insert"
        ' Check that the value is cur
        If ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "cur" Then
            ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Insert
            ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value = "new"
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2).Select
        End If
    End If
n = n + 1
Loop

' After rearranging the new and cur delete the extra columns if any
Do While ActiveCell.Value <> "Grand Total"

    If ActiveCell.Value <> "Grand Total" Or (ActiveCell.Value = "" And ActiveCell.Offset(0, 1).Value <> "") Then
        ActiveCell.EntireColumn.Delete
    End If
Loop
End Sub



Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    UserForm2.Hide

    ' Create a pivot table
    Call Create_Pivot_table

    ' This sub will rearrange the new and current under the class codes
    'Call Rearrange_Col

    ' This sub will format the table in sheet 3
    'Call Format_Table

    'MsgBox "Please check the format of the table in Sheet 3!"
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you point out which line causes the Error ?

Comment: What happens when you change `ActiveWorkbook` to `ThisWorkbook` in `Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook....`?

Comment: this line causes the error Set PTCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Add(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)

Comment: The result is also the same when it is changed to ThisWorkbook

Comment: Most likely unrelated, but please don't use this line `ix = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.row - 1 + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.count
` but use `Activesheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row` instead, as usedrange is very unreliable and can give you a number of problems and errors in the long run.

Comment: Oh Damn!!! Change `.Add` to `.Create` See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19659224/pivotcaches-add-errors-out)

Comment: i tried to add .create it didnt work

Comment: $A$1:$BH$3522 is the address

Comment: Just tested this `Set PRange = ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$BH$3522")` and then 
`Set PTCache = ThisWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=PRange)`. It works just fine

Comment: It did't work for me why?

Comment: I nearly tried everything :(